# How to convert ASP MSAccess SQL CDbl and LEFT in a select statement to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL statement in an ASP page querying the database and I need to convert it to MySQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT trelMapSU.Site, trelMapSU.MapNum, tlkpSUTyp.SUTyp,
        tblSU.SUNum, tlkpSUDesc.SUDesc, 
        CDbl(IIf(IsNumeric( [tblSU]![SUNum]),[tblSU]![SUNum], 
          Left([tblSU]![SUNum],
             InStr(1,[tblSU]![SUNum],'-')-1)
            )  
        )
FROM tlkpSUTyp
```

I am new to this and found that CDbl means to convert a value to a double which still make very little sense to me even with the examples I have found.  It also seems that the Left command returns a specified number of characters from the left side of a string.  A Little more clear but I am still not sure what this is trying to accomplish.  Can someone explain how to convert this to MySQL?

UPDATE

Could someone translate what this means:

```
CDbl(IIf(IsNumeric( [tblSU]![SUNum]),[tblSU]![SUNum], 
 Left([tblSU]![SUNum],
  InStr(1,[tblSU]![SUNum],'-')-1)
 )  
)
```

I think if I knew that I could get somewhere.

Comment: Well I would start by looking at the MySQL user manual to find a function that does the same things. Then try it, test it and see if it does as expected

Comment: Hint, look up [`CAST()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/)

Comment: This is Access code, not VBScript, the language used by the ancient ASP. Instead of trying to parse numbers stored as text, use different columns from the start. There are better ways to split text in MySQL as well, eg using regular expressions to capture text up to the first dash

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the clarification, I saw that but didn't know what to call it.  I am converting an existing ASP site using an existing database so I need to do pretty much the same thing as the original developer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Cool, I will look that up and give that a try.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what [ ] ! [ ] means?

Comment: `[table name]![column name]`

Comment: I meant the '!'.  Anyhow I found help here: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/statement-interpretation-and-cdbl.325879/